# asp.net core app publishs fine from gui but not cli

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, msbuild

i am trying to publish my asp.net core app from the cli in vscode.  The deployment works fine when i run it from within visual studio.  but i get an ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED when i run it in the cli.  I tried to saving the password in the options in visual studio but this did not change it.  the cli does not ask for a password either way nor do i know how to provide it.

My question is how do i get this to work publishing from the cli?

```
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\IISProfile.pubxml"
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the original .pubxml and trying again. If this doesn't solve your problem, please tell me your .net sdk and runtime version, we need to reproduce your problem to help you further.

Comment: @JasonPan i tried that and it did not solve the problem.  i am using .net6

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in my side, could you share the error details for us. By the way, pls check the link, it mentioned the issue related the firewall or something.

Comment: @JasonPan forgive me is I missed something obvious but what link are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link , https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8834#issuecomment-339806157